Pyarrow's S3FileSystem and versioned buckets
I'm using pyarrow's S3FileSystem to load hive-partitioned datasets from a versioned S3 bucket in a local MinIO object store. The files making up the dataset are deleted (and possibly re-written) quite frequently, which is the reason for the bucket being versioned - clients are expected to "hold on to a file version" as they see a file, and keep asking about that version.
It seems however that pyarrow's S3FileSystem doesn't implement any support for versioning; in fact, after instantiating a dataset object on a (prefix of) parquet files, pyarrow throws RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND AWS errors when materializing that dataset after any of the files is deleted, which wouldn't happen if pyarrow "held on" to the file versions it encounters.
Are there any options to enable versioning on the S3FileSystem object?
